# Aggregate score of four lists to one List

Tags: c#, list

I have lists of `Employee` objects. Employee class looks like this:

```
class Employee
{
   int empId,
   String empName,
   double score,
   String department
}
```

I have a dictionary object like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Employee>> = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
```

This dictionary has four keys(1, 2, 3, 4). A employee with a id may be present in all the four lists and may not be present. I want a aggregated list of Employee with score as sum of all the scores for an employee.

Example: If a employee with Id = 1, has score as 10, 20, 30 and 40 in four Lists, then the resultant List should have a entry for that Employee with score = 100. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LinQ:

```
var yourdict = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
var yourId = 17;

var score = yourDict.Values
                    .SelectMany(x => x)
                    .Where(emp => emp.empId == yourId)
                    .Select(x => x.score)
                    .Sum();
```

Or grouped for all:

```
var employeeIdsAndScores = yourDict.Values
                                   .SelectMany(x => x)
                                   .GroupBy(emp => emp.Id)
                                   .Select(g => new { EmployeeId = g.Key, Score = g.Select(x => x.score).Sum() } );

foreach(var emp in employeeIdsAndScores)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Employee Id={0} scored {1} points in total", emp.EmployeeId, emp.Score);
}
```

Comment: looks good but couple of edits: var yourId = 17; and .Where(emp => emp.empId == yourId)