# Copy distinct id's to a list

Tags: c#, list

I have 4 Lists, like this:

```
List <Emp> l1 = new List<Emp>();
List <Emp> l2 = new List<Emp>();
List <Emp> l3 = new List<Emp>();
List <Emp> l4 = new List<Emp>();
```

`Emp` has a property called `id`, How can I get a List of all distinct id's present in all the four Lists?

Comment: I [just showed you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455577/aggregate-score-of-four-lists-to-one-list) how to aggregate a variable number of lists and now you don't know how to do something simpler with a fixed number of lists? Maybe it's time to actually *learn* how to do this instead of posting every requirement you have as a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) for the DistinctBy :

```
 IEnumrable<Emp> uniqueEmps = l1.Concat(l2).Concat(l3).Concat(l4)
                                .DistinctBy(e => e.id);
```

for just the Id's :

```
 IEnumrable<int> uniqueIds = l1.Concat(l2).Concat(l3).Concat(l4)
                               .Select(e => e.id).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 5):

> How can I get a List of all distinct id's present in all the four Lists?

If you are looking for a list of IDs (as opposed to `Emp` objects that have these IDs) you can do it with a simple query:

```
var ids = l1.Concat(l2).Concat(l3).Concat(l4).Select(e => e.Id).Distinct();
```

Comment: +1 for the Concat, I had to look up the diff with Union first.

Answer (score 1):

If your emp class implements equality comparison then you can just union the lists together:

```
IEnumrable<int> uniqueIds = l1.Union(l2).Union(l3).Union(l4).Select(e => e.id);
```

To implement equality in your class, you simply override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var compareTo = obj as Emp;
    return Id.Equals(CompareTo.Id);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that anywhere you need to compare two `emp` instances, it will leverage this implementation.

Comment: But overriding Equality&HashCode can have consequences elsewhere. This won't work for e.g. uniquenames

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you provide a link to an example?  I am very curious what other issues this can introduce.